# Adding a class to an object depending on which file the object is being used

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm trying to add a class to a navigation bar depending on which file it's being used. The nav is located on header.php and it is being included on page2.php or page3.php but it needs a different color than the other pages. I'm still amateur so i tried using this javascript:

```
let url = window.location.pathname;
    let filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    let nav = $('.js--main-nav');
    if(filename == 'page2.php'|| filename == 'page3.php') {
        nav.addClass('black-nav');
    }
```

I want to add the class black-nav on the navigation which also has the class js--main-nav when it is used on page2 or page3 but don't add it when on other pages.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Is your issue related to Wordpress?

Comment: Hello! no, i'm writing the code myself

Comment: Just a suggestion _ Have you considered the option of making a copy of `header.php` and renaming it and styling it to suit your needs_ then have `page2` `page3` link to that instead? _ My suggestion is based on how Wordpress resolves the problem of differently styled headers

Comment: That could be a good answer but i don't want to add another file just to change the color of the header since it is a big project already.

Answer (score 2):

Hello i solved it by adding a php statement inside the class of the object like this:

```
<?php $pagename = basename(__FILE__, '.php'); ?>
...
...
<ul class="main-nav <?php if($pagename == 'page2' || $pagename == 'page3') { echo 'black-nav';} else { echo '';} ?> js--main-nav">
```

I didn't solved it with javascript but it seems to do the trick just fine!

Comment: well, your asked a question and there was some javascript code there, so I thought you were looking for some JavaScript solutions. 

Great to hear that you solved on your own. :thumbsup:

Comment: Well Done Jose! You've just provided Stack Overflow with a Question and an Answer! Officially an SO contributor! But you should also 'accept' the answer you have posted... (then watch what happens to your profile stats) ; )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried concinating class?

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
if(filename == 'page2.php'|| filename == 'page3.php') {
console.log('IF condition is fulfilled')
    nav.addClass('js--main-nav black-nav'); //here is the change
} else {
console.log('IF condition is not fulfilled')
}
```

Comment: does IF condition are getting fulfilled?